# R quantmod::getFinancials

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm using the `quantmod`package. I've got a vector of tickers like this :

```
c("AAPL","GOOG","IBM","GS","AMZN","GE")
```

and I want to create a function to calculate the EBIT margin of a stock (= operating income / total revenue). So for a given stock, I use the following piece of code which only works for GE (provided a ".f" is added a the end of the ticker) :

```
require(quantmod)
getFinancials("GE",period="A")
ebit.margin <- function(stock.ticker.f){
   return(stock.ticker$IS$A["Operating Income",]/stock.ticker$IS$A["Total Revenue",])
}
ebit.margin("GE")
```

I would like to generalize this function in order to use then the `apply`function. There are several difficulties :

- when applying the `quantmod::getFinancial`function to a ticker, the financial statements of the stocks are saved in the default environment. The `viewFinancial`has then to be used to get and print the financial statements. I need a way to get access to the financial statements directly into the function
- The function's argument function is a string like "GE.f" but it would more convenient to enter directly the ticker ("GE"). I've tried to use the `paste0` and `gsub` to get a string like "GE.f" it doesn't work because "GE.f" doesn't belong to the `financials` class.

To sum up, I'm a bit lost...

Comment: `period` is an argument for the `viewFinancials` function, and is not used by `getFinancials`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anaother option is to laod your tickers in an new environnement.

```
tickers <-  new.env()
s <- c("AAPL","GOOG","IBM","GS","AMZN","GE")
lapply(s, getFinancials,env=tickers)
sapply(ls(envir=tickers),
       function(x) {x <- get(x) ## get the varible name
                    x$IS$A["Operating Income", ] / x$IS$A["Total Revenue",]})

              AAPL.f     AMZN.f       GE.f    GOOG.f      GS.f     IBM.f
2012-09-29 0.3529596 0.01106510 0.11811969 0.2543099 0.2689852 0.2095745
2011-09-24 0.3121507 0.01792957 0.13753327 0.3068724 0.1676678 0.1964439
2010-09-25 0.2818704 0.04110630 0.09415548 0.3540466 0.2804621 0.1974867
2009-09-26 0.2736278 0.04606471 0.06387029 0.3514585 0.3837401 0.1776439
```

**EDIT**

No need to use `ls`, `get`.... just the handy `eapply` (thanks @GSee) which applies FUN to the named values from an environment and returns the results as a list

```
eapply(tickers, function(x) 
              x$IS$A["Operating Income", ] / x$IS$A["Total Revenue",])
```

Comment: or even `eapply(tickers, function(x) x$IS$A["Operating Income", ] / x$IS$A["Total Revenue",])`

Comment: @GSee brillant! `eapply`I don't know this one ! I already upvote your answer but +10 for eapply!

Comment: It's handy, but bear in mind that the order of the results will be arbitrary if the environment is hashed. (and, as best I can tell, in reverse order if it isn't hashed)

Comment: Of course..maybe the idea here, once you get your result(the indicator) you delete the environnment. I don't know very well quantmod so I can't say if using custom environment is the way...

Comment: Thanks agstudy and GSee for your very valuable answers. The function eapply is great!

Answer (score 6):

It's easier if you use `auto.assign=FALSE`

```
s <- c("AAPL","GOOG","IBM","GS","AMZN","GE")
fin <- lapply(s, getFinancials, auto.assign=FALSE)
names(fin) <- s
lapply(fin, function(x) x$IS$A["Operating Income", ] / x$IS$A["Total Revenue",])
#$AAPL
#2012-09-29 2011-09-24 2010-09-25 2009-09-26 
# 0.3529596  0.3121507  0.2818704  0.2736278 
#
#$GOOG
#2012-12-31 2011-12-31 2010-12-31 2009-12-31 
# 0.2543099  0.3068724  0.3540466  0.3514585 
#
#$IBM
#2012-12-31 2011-12-31 2010-12-31 2009-12-31 
# 0.2095745  0.1964439  0.1974867  0.1776439 
#
#$GS
#2012-12-31 2011-12-31 2010-12-31 2009-12-31 
#0.2689852  0.1676678  0.2804621  0.3837401 
#
#$AMZN
#2012-12-31 2011-12-31 2010-12-31 2009-12-31 
#0.01106510 0.01792957 0.04110630 0.04606471 
#
#$GE
#2012-12-31 2011-12-31 2010-12-31 2009-12-31 
#0.11811969 0.13753327 0.09415548 0.06387029
```