# How to fix ''Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors'' in stock analysis code (in R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, web-scraping, reshape2, quantmod

I am trying to run a code which focuses on

- Getting Stock Data
- Sorting and cleaning data
- Analyzing data

However I keep getting errors, where the first error that comes up is

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

**The code is the following:**

```
library(quantmod)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

##Choose stock tickers to grab data and other parameters
ticker <- c("MSFT","GOOG","AMZN","IBM")
ExpectedGrowthRate <- -1
MarginSafety <- .10
GrowthDeclineRate <- .05
DiscountRate <- .09
DCF_YearsProjection <- 5
LongTermGrowthRate <- .03


##Get the financial statement data of the tickers for the past four years
data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(ticker)){

  #Get the stock ticker information
  temp_data <- try(getFinancials(ticker[i], type=c('BS','IS','CF'), period=c('A'), auto.assign = FALSE), silent=TRUE)

  #Create temporary data frames for each of the financial statments
  temp_dataBS <- data.frame(temp_data$BS$A, FinancialStatement="BalanceSheet")
  temp_dataBS$Metric <- rownames(temp_dataBS)
  temp_dataIS <- data.frame(temp_data$IS$A, FinancialStatement="IncomeStatement")
  temp_dataIS$Metric <- rownames(temp_dataIS)
  temp_dataCF <- data.frame(temp_data$CF$A, FinancialStatement="CashFlow")
  temp_dataCF$Metric <- rownames(temp_dataCF)
  temp_data <- rbind(melt(temp_dataBS, id=c("Metric", "FinancialStatement")), melt(temp_dataIS, id=c("Metric", "FinancialStatement")), melt(temp_dataCF, id=c("Metric", "FinancialStatement")))


  #Rbind the data to append ticker information
  data <- rbind(data, cbind(temp_data, "Ticker"=ticker[i]))
}
```

In what way is this fixable?

**EDIT:** it seems that the problem lies in the function GetFinancials, as when I run the following code:

```
temp_data <- getFinancials("IBM", type=c('BS','IS','CF'), period=c('A'), auto.assign = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in thead[x]:thead[x + 1] : NA/NaN argument
```

Comment: If I try to run the "getfinancials" command for only one ticker (without loop), then I already seem to get an error.. so I think that the main problem lies in GetFinancials..

Comment: check this one `temp_data$BS$A,`

Comment: What is `BS`? What its values?

Comment: see this, may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034685/r-quantmodgetfinancials

Comment: @Alice ; it seems that the problem lies in the function getFinancials, as when I run the following code:

    temp_data <- getFinancials("IBM", type=c('BS','IS','CF'), period=c('A'), auto.assign = FALSE)

I get the following error:

    Error in thead[x]:thead[x + 1] : NA/NaN argument

Comment: I really would like to help. However, I could not install the` (quantmod)`

Comment: The reason for your errors  is that `getFinancials` wants to download the data from  Google which does not offer the data anymore! You can check  `getFinancials('CF', period='A', auto.assign = TRUE)` or any other symbol.